# Reading named Pipe using overlapped/asynchronous i/o

Tags: c++, windows, asynchronous, named-pipes, overlapped-io

I have a real old code from a service that uses named named pipes in message mode (`PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE`) with overlapped i/o (`FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`).

The code does the following:

1. `ReadFile` for 4 bytes with overlapped i/o (header + message length). The Client wrote this command with one call to `WriteFile`.
2. After the 4 bytes are read, a `ReadFile` call is made to read the rest of the message (with the known length) ***without*** specifying an `OVERLAPPED` structure.
3. After the command is executed the routine continues at stage 1. and awaits the next command.

When I read the documentation

> Overlapped operations require a file, named pipe, or communications device that was created with the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED flag. When a thread calls a function (such as the ReadFile function) to perform an overlapped operation, the *calling thread must specify* a pointer to an OVERLAPPED structure. (If this pointer is NULL, the function return value may incorrectly indicate that the operation completed.)

I have to assume that this code will not work or is at least be called **incorrect**...

In fact this code is 15 years old and runs on hundreds of machines and it works without problems.

So do I have to tell my boss and colleagues that this code is buggy and it is just **luck** that it works and this code need to be corrected?

Comment: See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120411-00/?p=7883 "I know that an overlapped file handle requires an lpOverlapped, but why does it (sometimes) work if I omit it?"

Answer (score 3):

yes, this code is incorrect but can work without errors.
`ReadFile`  call [`ZwReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwreadfile). it 5th parameter - IoStatusBlock - Pointer to an [`IO_STATUS_BLOCK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_io_status_block) structure - is mandatory and always must be not 0. for any file. for any I/O type. so `ReadFile` must pass pointer to [`IO_STATUS_BLOCK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_io_status_block) when it call [`ZwReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwreadfile). if you pass not 0 pointer to [`OVERLAPPED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-overlapped) - it pass this pointer as [`IO_STATUS_BLOCK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_io_status_block) to `ZwReadFile`. the first 2 members of `OVERLAPPED` corresponded to `IO_STATUS_BLOCK`. but if you pass 0 in place pointer of `OVERLAPPED` - `ReadFile` allocate local `IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb` variable and pass it to `ZwReadFile`. the `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` memory must be valid until I/O not completed. because at the end of I/O kernel write final status to this memory. from another side - if you local variable for `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` - it became not valid (point to arbitrary memory in stack) after `ReadFile` return. in case synchronous I/O - no problem here, because `ReadFile` not return until I/O not completed. but in case asynchronous I/O - this was UB - `ReadFile` can return while I/O still in progress. so `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` became not valid before I/O end. and when I/O actually ended - will be overwritten memory at arbitrary place in your thread stack. this can have no any effect or can corrupt your stack. undefinded. depend from where you be (which stack pointer value) at this time

Answer (score 2):

After reading more docs, I have to conclude that yes, the code can be said to be incorrect. Particularly these docs on `ReadFile`:

> A pointer to an OVERLAPPED structure is required if the hFile parameter was opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, otherwise it can be NULL.
>
> If hFile is opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, the lpOverlapped parameter must point to a valid and unique OVERLAPPED structure, otherwise the function can incorrectly report that the read operation is complete.

Bear in mind that the MS docs are updated over time, and the docs may have been less clear or incomplete at the time the code was written.

It probably happens to work because the pipe is in message mode. It's strange to have a length prefix header with message mode pipes in the first place, because the message mode handles message boundaries for you. In this specific scenario, the entire message would already be in the local OS so the incorrect synchronous read would always succeed.

Indeed, the protocol (with a separate header) sounds like it was designed to work with a byte stream abstraction such as a byte mode pipe or TCP/IP connection. It is possible that the protocol was originally designed for byte mode pipes and they switched to message mode pipes when it wasn't working (the synchronous `ReadFile` may behave unexpectedly on a byte mode pipe since the message may not be completely present yet).

Comment: I can follow all code changes in the TFS back to 2009. Before that date, the code was in Visual Source Safe and I have no more backup of the older code changes. Seams to be a plausible explanation. But in fact even in message mode: Isn't it possible that if the sender writes two messages (WriteFile, WriteFile), and the the receiver is calling ReadFile once with a large buffer that the receives 2 messages if the fit into the read buffer? I never checked that out...

Comment: @xMRi: I'm pretty sure that it would be different reads (assuming `PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE` is used). Not 100% sure, though; I haven't tested it and it's been... 20 years?... since I've used named pipes.

Comment: mode of pipe here absolute unrelated